# Is there a way to not send cookies when making an XMLHttpRequest on the same origin?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on an extension that parses the gmail rss feed for users. I allow the users to specify username/passwords if they don't want to stay signed-in. But this breaks for multiple sign-in if the user is signed-in and the username/password provided is for a different account. So I want to avoid sending any cookies but still be able to send the username/password in the send() call.

Answer (score 5):

As of Chrome 42, the [`fetch` API](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org) allows Chrome extensions (and web applications in general) to perform cookie-less requests. [HTML5 Rocks offers an introductory tutorial on using the fetch API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch).

Advanced documentation on `fetch` is quite sparse at the moment, but the [API interface from the specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class) is a great starting point. The fetch algorithm described below the interface shows that requests generated by `fetch` have no credentials by default!

```js
fetch('http://example.com/').then(function(response) {
    return response.text(); // <-- Promise<String>
}).then(function(responseText) {
    alert('Response body without cookies:\n' + responseText);
}).catch(function(error) {
    alert('Unexpected error: ' + error);
});
```

If you want truly anonymous requests, you could also disable the cache:

```js
fetch('http://example.com/', {
    // credentials: 'omit', // this is the default value
    cache: 'no-store',
}).then(function(response) {
    // TODO: Handle the response.
    // https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#response-class
    // https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using the [chrome.cookies module](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html). The idea is to get the current cookies, save them, remove them from the browser's cookie store, send your request, and finally restore them:

```
var cookies_temp = []; // where you put the cookies first
var my_cookie_store = []; // the cookies will be there during the request
var details = {/*your code*/}; // the first parameter for chrome.cookies.getAll()
var start_kidnapping = function(cookies) {
    cookies_temp = cookies.slice();
    kidnap_cookie();
};
var kidnap_cookie = function() {
    // This recursive function will store the cookies from cookies_temp to
    // my_cookie_store and then remove them from the browser's cookie store.
    if (cookies_temp.length == 0) { // when no more cookies, end recursion
        send_request();
    };
    else {
        var cookie = cookies_temp.pop();
        // We store url as a property since it is useful later.
        // You may want to change the scheme.
        cookie.url = "http://" + cookie.domain + cookie.path;
        my_cookie_store.push(cookie); // save it
        chrome.cookies.remove({url: cookie.url, name: cookie.name}, kidnap_cookie);
    };
};
var send_request = function() {
    // Send your request here. It can be asynchronous.
    for (var i = 0, i < my_cookie_store.length; i++){
        delete cookie.hostOnly; // these 2 properties are not part of the
        delete cookie.session;  // object required by chrome.cookies.set()
        // note that at this point, cookie is no longer a Cookie object
        chrome.cookies.set(my_cookie_store[i]); // restore cookie
    };
    my_cookie_store = []; // empty it for new adventures
};
chrome.cookies.getAll(details, start_kidnapping); // start
```

Alternatively, a simpler solution is to open an incognito window which will send the request, using the [chrome.windows module](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html), but this will prevent you from communicating with the rest of your extension. Note that you may have to change the `incognito` property of your manifest to `split`:

```
var incognito_window = {
    "url": "incognito.html",
    "focused": false, // do not bother user
    "incognito": true
}
chrome.windows.create(incognito_window);
```

Comment: should the `delete cookie.hostOnly;` and `delete cookie.session;` lines actually be `delete my_cookie_store[i].hostOnly;` and `delete my_cookie_store[i].session;` respectively?